# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column users.contact_id does not exist on ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I got this error when going to one my ressources called "Fils":

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.contact_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."contact_id" = ...
                                             ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."contact_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

I don't understand why the query looks on `user.contact_id` instead of `fil.contact_id` (I'm beginning in rails but i don't think it's the good behavior)

Fil table on schema.rb :

```
create_table "fils", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "contact_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "channel"
  end
```

Fil model :

```
class Fil < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :check_or_connect_messageries, :if =>:new_record?

  has_one :contact, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => "contact_id" 
  has_one :user, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => "user_id" 

  validates :contact_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  before_create :set_channel
  after_find :set_channel # des fois que
```

User model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :check_genres
  before_validation :set_image
  before_validation :init_attrs
  before_save :create_mangopay_bank_account
  before_create :set_name
  before_create :create_mangopay
  after_create :set_centres_interets
  after_create :set_preferences_musicales
  after_create :check_on_create
  after_update :check_on_update


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_one :preferences_voyage,  dependent: :destroy
  has_one :verification,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :badges,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favoris ,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :centres_interets,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :preferences_musicales,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recommandations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reputations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :routes,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trajets_reguliers,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :vehicules,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications,  dependent: :destroy

  validates :date_naissance, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  attr_accessor :points_communs
  attr_accessor :modele # created/booked/archived
  attr_accessor :peut_laisser_commentaire
  attr_accessor :est_abonne
  attr_accessor :est_bloque
  attr_accessor :a_vehicule
```

admin/user.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

menu parent: "Utilisateurs"
permit_params :name, :nickname, :email , :image, :genre,:statut, :fume, :etudes

index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :name
    column :nickname
    column :email
    column "Image" do |user|
        image_tag user.image, size: "50"
    end
    column :genre
    column :statut
    column :fume
    column :etudes
    column :profession
    actions
end
end
```

Comment: post your `admin/user.rb`

Comment: post updated with admin/user.rb

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Fil belongs_to User` and `User has_one Fil` ?

Comment: if `Fil has_one :user` then you should have `fil_id` in `users` table

Comment: or revert your `associations`

Comment: Works with your answer @Mathias ! Thanks !

Comment: Cool. I post it as an answer. Would appreciate it if you could accept it then. @CharlesDuporge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Fil belongs_to User` and `User has_one Fil` since the lookup happens in the fils-table.

A good basic read can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association